# Haskell PFP library problems

Tags: haskell

I am trying to run these [examples](http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~erwig/pfp/) using their [library](http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~erwig/pfp/pfp-jun06.tar.gz). When I run the command ghci Dice.hs, even if I am in the same folder with Dice.hs it tells

```
$ ghci Dice.hs
GHCi, version 7.6.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.

Probability.hs:5:8:
    Could not find module `Monad'
    It is a member of the hidden package `haskell98-2.0.0.2'.
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I also installed `mtl` package with Cabal. Other ideas?

Comment: This code is very old so it probably won't compile anyways. If you really want to try to run it, you'll have to expose the package: `ghc-pkg expose haskell98` .

Comment: Now I get another error ghci Dice.hs
GHCi, version 7.6.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.

Top level:
    Ambiguous interface for `Prelude':
      it was found in multiple packages: base haskell98-2.0.0.2